# How to get the names of an object's properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

Below code from URL (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_state_forin) returns "John Doe 25".
How can I fetch the property names like "fname lname age"?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <p>Click the button to loop through the properties of an object.</p>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
      <p id="demo"></p>
      <script>
         function myFunction() {
             var person = {fname:"John", lname:"Doe", age:25}; 

             var text = "";
             var x;
             for (x in person) {
                 text += person[name] + " ";
             }
             document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `name` isn't defined in your code. Did you mean `person[x]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an array of all of the object properties (aka keys!) using the `keys` function:

```
Object.keys(person);
```

So to print out the list of key/value pairs you can do:

```
var person = { fname:"John", lname:"Doe", age:25 }; 
var personProps = Object.keys(person);
for(var i = 0; i < personProps.length; i++){
    var key = personProps[i];
    var value = person[key];
    console.log(key + " : " + value);
}
```

Or you can loop around the object's properties directly as follows:

```
var person = { fname:"John", lname:"Doe", age:25 }; 
for (key in person) {
    console.log(key + " : " + person[key]);
};
```

Output:

```
fname : John
name : Doe
age : 25
```

Comment: Thank you Matthew and everyone for your quick assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.keys(yourObj)` to get an array of keys. Like:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var person = {
    fname: "John",
    lname: "Doe",
    age: 25
  };

  var text = "";
  var x;
  var keys = Object.keys(person);
  for (x = 0; x < keys.length; x++) {
    text += keys[x] + " ";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You see that loop:

```
for (x in person) {
    text += person[name] + " ";
}
```

x will be the properties of the person object.

Answer (score 0):

A [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop already iterates over the keys of the object. You just change `person[x]` to `x`.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('tryit');
var output = document.getElementById('demo');
var person = { fname: "John", lname: "Doe", age: 25 };

button.onclick = function() {
  var text = "";
  for (var x in person) {
    text += x + " ";
  }
  output.innerHTML = text;
};
```

```html
<p>Click the button to loop through the properties of an object.</p>
<button id="tryit">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

It's also common to use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) along with [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to do the same thing, but without iterating over any inherited properties from the `prototype` of the object.

```
var text = "";
Object.keys(person).forEach(function(x) {
    text += x + " ";
});
```